# How to connect with SLIM REST api with MS SQL server?

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to get results from an API call using Slim connecting with MSSQLSERVER2012

the example used to work with MYSQL getconnection function (see below) but when I am trying to 
connect with MsSQL server 2012 I am getting an error like "api call error "invalid data source name"

http://localhost/msapi/api.php/clients

1'api call error "invalid data source name"

```
require '/Slim/Slim.php';

$app = new Slim();

$app->get('/clients', 'getClients');

$app->run();

function getClients() {
    $sql = "select * FROM clients";

    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $clients = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo '{"client": ' . json_encode($clients) . '}';
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}


function getConnection_MYSQL() {
    $dbhost="SERVER";
    $dbuser="USER";
    $dbpass="PASSWORD";
    $dbname="DB";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}


function getConnection() {
    $dbhost="SERVER";
    $dbuser="USER";
    $dbpass="PASSWORD";
    $dbname="DB";
    $dbh = new PDO ("ADODB.Connection");

      $connStr = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=".$dbhost.";UID=".$dbuser.";PWD=".$dbpass.";DATABASE=".$dbname;  
      $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
      $dbh->open($connStr); //Open the connection to the database  

    return $dbh;
}
```

the function getConnection_MYSQL() is an example that works.
But the getConnection() tryis to connect with MS SQL server ?

Do you see why I am getting an "invalid data source name" with the function getConnection()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't post an alternative DSN-string, I'm assuming you are using the one from your example and just replace host, username and password. This won't work.

When you are running your Slim-application on a windows host you can (and should) use [Microsoft's SQL Server Driver for PHP (sqlsrv)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx).

There are 2 versions sqlsrv.dll and pdo_sqlsrv.dll. When you want to reuse most of your code you should use the latter. This way you probably only have to modify your DSN (see [php docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php)):

```
new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=testdb", "UserName", "Password");
```

If you are using the first you have to update the way you connect to the db and create the query. You can read the [Beginner's Guide](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/whitepaper-accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx) to see a few examples that should make it easy.

If you are running not running your application on a Windows-machine you will probably have to set up ODBC and FreeTDS and then use PDO with an ODBC-DSN. From my experience this will be quite a lot of work, but there are a few good tutorials out there. Just google for "freetds sql server".

Comment: Thank you very much.Totally helpful resource your answer!